# Liferay: Call JSON service from portlet

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I'm trying to call a json web service with my portlet javascript code:
In the `js/main.js` i have:

```
   Liferay.Service(
  '/Basic-portlet.hello/remote-hello',
  {
    name: ''
  },
  function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
);
```

this call executes only once when I add the portlet to the page, whenever page reloaded a javascript error raised:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
A.mix.parseIOConfig
A.mix.parseInvokeArgs
Service    main.js?browserId=other&lan....
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen when you try to invoke a Liferay JSON web service from a context without access to AlloyUI.

Add the following AUI import:

```
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
```

Then wrap your service invocation like this:

```
AUI().use('aui-base', function(A){
  // Liferay Service invocation here
});
```

E.g.,

```
AUI().use('aui-base', function(A){
  Liferay.Service(
    '/user/get-user-by-email-address',
    {
      companyId: Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getCompanyId(),
      emailAddress: 'test@liferay.com'
    },
    function(obj) {
      console.log(obj);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issues in past. Try disabling the javascript minifier and see if that solves your issue. It fixed my issue.

Thanks,
Gaurav